# Grails: Convert the Hql query to GORM

Tags: grails, orm, hql, grails-orm

Kindly, Convert this below hql query to GORM either using criteria or using some API. I am new to grails and I searched enough but I did't get any positive solution for this forgive me if it is simple.

> MappingDetail.executeQuery("select map.id from MappingMaster as map where map.id = (select mapdetail.id from MappingDetail as mapdetail where mapdetail.rawdata_template.id=(select rawdata.id from  RawDataMasterTemplate as rawdata where rawdata.name like :name))",[name:'%Rick%'])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have to use criteria here? I think this is the select where you use HQL instead.

```
def raw = RawDataMasterTemplate.findByNameLike('%Rick%')
def detail = MappingDetail.findByRawdata_template(raw)
def master = MappingMaster.get(detail?.id)
```

Comment: Why are three database queries better than one?

Comment: I didn't say they are, and I for myself would rather use op's HQL instead. But he said he wanted GORM. I doubt this can be written in criteria either.

Answer (score 1):

Test this:

```
MappingMaster.withCriteria {
  createAlias 'mappingDetail', 'mp'
  createAlias 'mp.rawDtaMasterTemplate', 'rd'
  projections {
    property 'id'
  }
  ilike 'rd.name', '%Rick%'
}
```